# what's the difference between these classes in Kotlin?

Tags: class, kotlin

I'm a beginner in Kotlin!
Can we explain the difference between these classes in Kotlin

```
class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)

class Person(name: String, age: Int)

class Person(var name: String,var age: Int)
```

And how I add getter and setter for data class in Kotlin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you should try to read the difference in the manual:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html

But lets try to explain this:

```
class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)
```

The Kotlin compiler will generate for both constructor arguments corresponding fields storing the values and will generate respecting getters. The values are immutable because of the keyword `val` so there will not be any setters.

```
class Person(name: String, age: Int)
```

The arguments are only passed to the constructor but not stored as fields. So there will also be no getters and setters.

```
class Person(var name: String, var age: Int)
```

Like in the first example the values are stored in generated fields. But the values are mutable because of the keyword `var` so the compiler will generate getters and setters.

`data` is an additional (optional) keyword to put in front of the `class` declaration. This will in addition to the getters and setters generate a `toString` method printing the values of all attributes with their names and a `hashCode` method taking every value into account. As getters and setters are generated for `data` classes you don't need to add them manually.

Kotlin is a lot about reducing the manual work required to do by the developer in Java to be done by the compiler of Kotlin.